# Messages are not getting delayed in Botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm posting two messages back to the user as a reply as below,

```
static Timer t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerEvent));
static Timer t1 = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerEventInActivity));
static int timeOut = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["disableEndConversationTimer"]); //3600000

public static void CallTimer(int due) {
  t.Change(due, Timeout.Infinite);
}

public static void CallTimerInActivity(int due) {
  t1.Change(due, Timeout.Infinite);
}

public async static Task PostAsyncWithDelay(this IDialogContext ob, string text) {
  try {
    var message = ob.MakeMessage();
    message.Type = Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ActivityTypes.Message;
    message.Text = text;
    await PostAsyncWithDelay(ob, message);

    CallTimer(300000);

    if ("true".Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["disableEndConversation"])) {
      CallTimerInActivity(timeOut);
    }

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Trace.TraceInformation(ex.Message);
  }

}

await context.PostAsyncWithDelay("Great!");
await context.PostAsyncWithDelay("I can help you with that.");
```

But, there is no delay between them when received. Both messages are received in one go.

How can I delay the second message with some time?

Comment: @AnitaGeorge What's the interest? It will not delay the next reply

Comment: @Raviteja: Where does your method "PostAsyncWithDelay" come from?

Comment: `PostAsyncWithDelay` is not a method in the botbuilder SDK.  It seems like a custom method you wrote or got from somewhere. It would probably be helpful to post the code of the method and not assume that everyone magically knows what it is.

Comment: @JasonSowers updated the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Root Dialog**

To delay your message you can use Task.Delay method. Change your PostAsyncWithDelay as:

```
public async static Task PostAsyncWithDelay(IDialogContext context, string text)
{
        await Task.Delay(4000).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var message = context.MakeMessage();
            message.Text = text;
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
            {
                var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
                client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync((Activity)message);
            }

        });
}
```

You can call PostAsyncWithDelay method when you want to delay a message, otherwise use context.PostAsync method to send your messages.

```
  private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
  {
          //Sending a message nomally
          await context.PostAsync("Hi");

          //Notify the user that the bot is typing
          var typing = context.MakeMessage();
          typing.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
          await context.PostAsync(typing);

          //The message you want to delay. 
          //NOTE: Do not use context.PostAsyncWithDelay instead simply call the method.
          await PostAsyncWithDelay(context, "2nd Hi");
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Here is what you get]

Comment: But there is no loader coming between two messages. How could the user know there is one more message to come?

Comment: You can send a typing message between two messages. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Raviteja Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah. It's almost what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I delay the second message with some time?

If you’d like to delay sending the second message, you can try the following code snippet:

```
await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} at {DateTime.Now}");

Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    using (var scope = Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
    {
        var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"I can help you with that..");
        client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }
});

context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
```

Besides, as others mentioned in comments, the method `PostAsyncWithDelay` seems not a built-in method in Bot Builder SDK. If you try to achieve the requirement and defined that custom method, you can post the code of that method.

Comment: Hi @Raviteja, Anita George use the same approach as I shared in my reply, did you tried my solution after I provided it?

Answer (score 1):

To make all replies delay, you may insert this directly in the controller.

```
       if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            Activity isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply();
            isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(isTypingReply);

            var message = isTypingReply;
            await Task.Delay(4000).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
                {

                }

            });


            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
        }
```